# Ingress rule same path but different backend, depending on http or https request

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

Is there any way with Ingress to control the service and port destination depending on whether the request is http or https?

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

http://localhost/my_path -> http://service:9955/my_path

https://localhost/my_path -> https://service:9443/my_path

For example, I've been using this configuration in nginx.conf and works as expected:

```
    server {
        server_name localhost;

        listen 80;

        location /my_path {
           proxy_pass  http://service:9955/my_path;
        }
    }

    server {    
        server_name localhost;

        listen 443 ssl;

        location /my_path {
           proxy_pass  https://service:9443/my_path;
        }
    }
```

I tried to reproduce this configuration in Ingress.yaml but I can't find a way to define which rule belongs to http and which one to https.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  annotations:
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:

          - path: /my_path
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  number: 9955

          - path: /my_path
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  number: 9443
```

Thank you for your time.